# file.exists() incorrectly returns false on java/mac computer?

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
    File f = new File(fileSystemPath);
    if(!f.exists())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Static File="+getCanonicalPath(f)+" does not exist. fileSysPath="+this.fileSystemPath);
```

which results in the following exception

```
WEBPIECESxPACKAGE.TestLesson1Json > testSynchronousController FAILED
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Static File=/Library/Workflow/webpieces/webserver/webpiecesServerBuilder/templateProject/WEBPIECESxAPPNAME/src/dist/public/favicon.ico does not exist. fileSysPath=public/favicon.ico
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.StaticRoute.<init>(StaticRoute.java:44)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.model.R1RouterBuilder.addStaticRoute(R1RouterBuilder.java:89)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.model.R1RouterBuilder.addStaticFile(R1RouterBuilder.java:82)
    at org.webpieces.router.api.routing.AbstractRoutes.addStaticFile(AbstractRoutes.java:38)
    at WEBPIECESxPACKAGE.base.AppRoutes.configure(AppRoutes.java:44)
    at org.webpieces.router.api.routing.AbstractRoutes.configure(AbstractRoutes.java:12)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.RouteLoader.loadAllRoutes(RouteLoader.java:171)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.RouteLoader.loadImpl(RouteLoader.java:114)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.RouteLoader.load(RouteLoader.java:73)
    at org.webpieces.router.impl.ProdRouterService.start(ProdRouterService.java:49)
    at org.webpieces.webserver.impl.WebServerImpl.startAsync(WebServerImpl.java:68)
    at org.webpieces.webserver.impl.WebServerImpl.startSync(WebServerImpl.java:54)
    at WEBPIECESxPACKAGE.Server.start(Server.java:232)
    at WEBPIECESxPACKAGE.TestLesson1Json.setUp(TestLesson1Json.java:73)
```

Yet when I put a breakpoint in my program right at the if statement, I do the ls -la command with this result BEFORE and AFTER the exists check(ie. it exists just fine)

```
[08:22][ruby-1.9.3][dhiller:/Library/Workflow/webpieces(master)]$ ls -la /Library/Workflow/webpieces/webserver/webpiecesServerBuilder/templateProject/WEBPIECESxAPPNAME/src/dist/public/favicon.ico
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dhiller  wheel  1150 Jul  4 09:31 /Library/Workflow/webpieces/webserver/webpiecesServerBuilder/templateProject/WEBPIECESxAPPNAME/src/dist/public/favicon.ico
[08:22][ruby-1.9.3][dhiller:/Library/Workflow/webpieces(master)]$
```

Instead of new File, I tried this out which did not help either

```
private File createFile(String fileSystemPath2) {
    String[] split = fileSystemPath2.split("/");
    File tmp = new File(split[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
        tmp = new File(tmp, split[i]);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

I am on jdk 1.8.0_111 and mac 10.11.6.  The one thing that has worked was appending user.dir to the beginning of the File so something like

```
String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
File f = new File(userDir, systemPath)
```

Why do I need to do this though?  This seems odd as I could have sworn this worked before?

Comment: How come you have `getCanonicalPath(f)` instead of `f.getCanonicalPath()`?

Comment: I have a try ..catch to convert it to a runtimeexception inside getCanonicalPath() method instead of propagating a useless checked exception that users can do nothing about fixing to the top level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured it out which leaves me with yet another question.

I modify the user.dir System property but this apparently breaks relative files from actually working (at least in jdk1.8.0_111).  ie. it works as long as files are relative ONLY to the original user.dir.  Unfortunately, the user.dir that intellij picks, gradle picks and eclipse picks are all inconsistent :( so I thought I would align them and modify the user.dir so all would work....ooops, wrong.  that does not work.

I added this question on SO next on the bug I see which is the trimmed down version.

[user.dir property broken on OSX jdk 1.8.0_111? how about other OS, versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130661/user-dir-property-broken-on-osx-jdk-1-8-0-111-how-about-other-os-versions)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you **do** need to append the user home dir to that path because otherwise it would not be an absolute path and your application would be able to find it only if it's located in a folder, which this path can be resolved from (in user home in your case).

Comment: that is not true.  In fact, I found another test that works just fine and logged the absolute path and canonical path of teh 'relative' file and it logs the whole entire path.

Comment: added the test on post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130661/user-dir-property-broken-on-osx-jdk-1-8-0-111-how-about-other-os-versions that demonstrates what I think must be a bug.