# user.dir property broken on OSX jdk 1.8.0_111? how about other OS, versions?

Tags: java

I only have this mac and am wondering if this issue exists on other OS's or perhaps jdks.  This test fails where the 2nd to last line verifies the absolute path is referencing a real file(and matches the first file abs path) BUT the f2.exists call returns false like it does not exist.

I am curious on windows and linux if this also fails?

```
@Test
public void testUserDirProp() {
    File f = new File("src/test/resources/logback-test.xml");

    //assert absolute path is correct
    Assert.assertEquals("/Library/Workflow/webpieces/core/core-util/src/test/resources/logback-test.xml", f.getAbsolutePath());
    Assert.assertTrue(f.exists());

    //NOW, change user.dir
    System.setProperty("user.dir", "/Library/Workflow/webpieces/core/core-util/src");

    //Now, f2 is relative to NEW user.dir property
    File f2 = new File("test/resources/logback-test.xml");

    //verify absolute path is still the full correct path for f2 and it is
    Assert.assertEquals("/Library/Workflow/webpieces/core/core-util/src/test/resources/logback-test.xml", f2.getAbsolutePath());

    //since absolute path was correct, it should exist 
    Assert.assertTrue(f2.exists());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user.dir` property isn't broken. *Setting* it isn't supported, and isn't guaranteed to behave in any specific way. See http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4117557 and the linked tickets:

> After careful consideration, we still do not believe that the current behaviour can/should be changed.  We have never guaranteed that "user.dir" will be consulted at any given time and unfortunately the jdk has assumed that this property will not change.  Ideally we'd introduce the concept of a "read-only" system property to guard against unsupported changes in this and other system properties.
>
> "user.dir", which is initialized during jvm startup, should be used as an 
>   informative/readonly system property, try to customize it via command line
>   -Duser.dir=xyz will end up at implementation dependend/unspecified behavior.
>   The current FileSystem implementation heavily depends on the assumption that
>   we dont have a "chdir" or "chdir" like functionality (like use -Duser.dir=xyz)
>   that will change the "current user dir" to not the one jvm startup from.
>   That said, the inconsistent behavior of FileIn/OutputStream is indeed a buggy
>   behavior (FileIn/OutputStream's open impl goes down to naive open directly
>   without consulting java File/FileSystem because of the assumption mentioned
>   above).
>
> To change the current implementation to support "customizable" user.dir is
>   a big deal, lots of classes/lines of change, only do it if we believe it's
>   really worth doing.

Comment: oh, thanks!  Man, it sure would be nice if they threw an exception then when it is set so we all knew that.  seem like they should fail fast rather than let people waste time with weird odd issues.  oh well.